# sympy: sometimes getting 'Integer' object has no attribute 'strip' after using parse_expr

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

After using parse_expr like this:

```
s = parse_expr(s, transformations=standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,))
```

Where s is different kinds of math (ie. 3+2 or 2x+5).
The problem is when s is just a integer/float the function results in "'Integer' object has no attribute 'strip'"

My workaround is just to check if s is a number. I'm just wondering if there is a way to safely use parse_expr without it crashing for integers.

Update: had a glitch with my server so casting to str didn't actually cast. Restarted the server and now casting to string works:

```
s = str(s)
```

Comment: Do you mean you use a python number type for `s` like `3` or a string containing a number like `'3'`? `s` has to be a string. Any other type violates the contract of [parse_expr](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html#parsing-functions-reference)

Comment: As i said casting it to str won't work.

Comment: Using your code for `s=2` shows exactly your error message but if `s='2'` there is no problem. [See here](http://live.sympy.org/?evaluate=from%20sympy.parsing.sympy_parser%20import%20*%0A%23--%0As%3D2%0A%23--%0As%20%3D%20parse_expr%28s%2C%20transformations%3Dstandard_transformations%20%2B%20%28implicit_multiplication_application%2C%29%29%0A%23--%0As%3D%272%27%0A%23--%0As%20%3D%20parse_expr%28s%2C%20transformations%3Dstandard_transformations%20%2B%20%28implicit_multiplication_application%2C%29%29%0A%23--%0As%0A%23--%0A).

Comment: You can say it as often as you like to but the problem seems to be that `s` is of integer type and **not** string.

Comment: You miss the closing `)` of your function call too

Comment: Yeah but shouldn't str(2) be the same as '2'?

Comment: Found out i had a weird glitch with my server that only updated it partways, so casting to string didn't take effect..

Comment: Yes `str(2)` is the same as `'2'` and if I test your code with `s=2` and `parse_expr(str(s))` on http://live.sympy.org it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always casting to string is better than checking for numbers. So if your getting the same error just do: `s = str(s)`

Answer (score 0):

Docstring:

```
Converts the string ``s`` to a SymPy expression, in ``local_dict``

Parameters
==========

s : str
    The string to parse.
```

`s` has to be a string.